# PHP regular expression returns blank array

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Problem :
I need **u69ruczh** as output this  from below code

```
$string = '<a data-mce-href="{{file:u69ruczh}}" href="{{file:u69ruczh}}">pptexamples.ppt</a>';
```

Generated output :

Array ( [0] => Array ( ) )

I have tried below code :

```
$string = '<a data-mce-href="{{file:u69ruczh}}" href="{{file:u69ruczh}}">pptexamples.ppt</a>';
$url = preg_match_all('/href=[\{\{file:(.*?)\}\}]/', $string, $match);
print_r($match);
```

Please assist me where did it goes wrong

Comment: Remove `[` and `]` from the regex pattern.

Comment: removed  [ and ] but still output blank array  : Array ( [0] => Array ( ) [1] => Array ( ) )

Comment: Sure, because [there must be a `"` after `=`](https://ideone.com/xQnRsY).

Answer (score 1):

If this format is standard this solution should also get you the desired output:

```
$string = '<a data-mce-href="{{file:u69ruczh}}" href="{{file:u69ruczh}}">pptexamples.ppt</a>';
$arr = explode(":",$string);
$substr = $arr[1];
$subarr = explode("}",$substr);
$finalstr = $subarr[0];
echo $finalstr;
// Output: u69ruczh
```

Answer (score 1):

This could be done simply using below regex.

`$url = preg_match_all('/file\:([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/', $string, $match);`

Comment: there can be special character also in string

Comment: $url = preg_match_all('/href="\{\{file:(.*?)\}\}"/', $string, $match);